Flutter update single data records in FutureBuilder
Situation:
I am using Flutter Web only (requirement). I have some kind of a DataTable (wrapped for style issues)in a StatefulWidget, which shows the customer data fetched from the backend. The DataTable is defined within a FutureBuilder that I can handle the different states of the Future e.g. loading time with a CircularProgressIndicator, showing errors, ...
Now we implemented a new feature: If another user changes the shown customer data, the backend is sending a notification to the client. This notifications include the updated data record (just the single data row). So I want to update the shown DataTable with the fetched data and the updated data record without fetching the server again since the request is quite slow (processing in the backend take some time, reasons are known and can currently not be avoided).
Problem/Question:
So my question/problem is that I dont have access to the data from the future as it is already done and in final state. Should I copy the data list locally once I receive it from the backend, but will I get the copied list with the updated data record back into the Future and the DataTable. Is there some other good solution/best practise for this issue?
Some Code:
Here is some code, I removed some unimportant parts that are not related to this topic and censored some variables and class names since our company name is in there. I hope it still makes sense and all relevant information is included:
class _CustomerListState extends State<CustomerList> {

Future<List<CustomerData>>? _customerData;

@override
void initState() {
    _customerData = Provider.of<apiService>(context, listen: false).fetchCustomerData(http.Client());
    super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _customerData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                return const Text("...");
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Column(children: [
                    Text("Loading ..."),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                ]);
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("An error occured: ${snapshot.error.toString()}");
                } else {
                    var tableData = snapshot.data;
                    return WrappedDataTable(
                        columns: columnHeader,
                        rows: tableData!.map((data) {
                            return WrappedDataTableRow(
                                cells: [
                                    WrappedDataTableCell(text: data.firstName ?? "-"),
                                    WrappedDataTableCell(text: data.lastName ?? "-"),
                                    WrappedDataTableCell(text: data.age ?? "-"),
                                ],
                            );
                        }).toList()));
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
}


first change your future as below
  Future<List<CustomerData>>? getCustomerData(bool? isUpdated) async {
          if(!isUpdated){
                 customerData = Provider.of<apiService>(context, 
                 listen:false).fetchCustomerData(http.Client());
               }else{
                 customerData = _customerData;
            }
        return customerData;
      }

Then add logic ,if the backend is updated get the updated row id & find it in currentList of customerData & update it locally and rebuild so it will be updated !

I had sth similiar which didnt work:
On the else part: _customerData is still a Future right? If yes then I cant access the data in it since it is already completed/done
Or is _customerData now a local "List" copied from the resolved future?

rebuilding the state eg.calling seState will again call the  getCustomerData func so it receives the updated data which is updated from notification client !
